# The maximum of $W_t-t$ with respect to $t$

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I’m asked to calculate

$$ P\left(\sup_{t\geq 0} W_t-t-1\geq 0\right)$$

Where $W_t$ is the Brownian motion.

I tried to calculate it as the way I calculated the distribution of $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t} W_s$ by considering the stopping time $\tau_b=\inf\{t>0,W_t-t=b\}$ for $b>0$.

But, here I can’t say $\tau_b$ is a stopping time with finite expection, which is important in calculating the distribution of  $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t} W_s$. So, I don’t know how to do it now.

Comment: What do you mean you can't say $\tau_b$ is a stopping time? It looks like a stopping time to me.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I wanted to say it doesn’t have a finite expectation. You are right.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I think this is exactly the answer. I didn’t find it that time. A lot thanks for your help!